# cv.glmnet vs glm vs lm.ridge

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, ridge-regression, glmnet

I am currently trying to build a ridge regression model, and knows that the lm.ridge, glm and cv.glmnet functions can enable me to do so. However, I really do not know what are the differences between these 3 functions apart from the fact that the 3 functions can give me different results. Does anyone know the rationale of each of the 3 functions in R? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is certainly in the R documentation, but here's a quick rundown.

A generalized linear model is a regression model whereby we can model data arising from exponential family distributions. A standard linear model assumes data arise from a particular kind of normal distribution, hence making the standard linear model a subcase of the general linear model.

The $glm$ function in R fits data under the assumptions of a given exponential family distribution (which you must specify).

There's one further wrinkle you must understand to get the difference between these three functions, and that's a concept called "penalized regression". Penalized regression adds a penalty to the size of the regression coefficients given by $\beta$ in the optimization problem in an effort to mitigate overfitting to the data. $lm.ridge$ and $cv.glmnet$ are solving these "penalized" regression problems. Specifically, $lm.ridge$ fits a penalized standard linear model to the data, whereas $cv.glmnet$ will fit a penalized general linear model to the data, so again, if you want to use $cv.glmnet$, you'll need to specify an exponential family distribution for your model to assume.

There's much more subtlety to these concepts than I can provide in these couple paragraphs, so I encourage you to read a bit more on the concepts I mentioned before fitting your data.